# like + gerund is these sentences are correct

Tags: word-usage

I studied that I can use like in two ways which is : 
like + gerund or like + to-infinitive .... I understand this grammar. 
my question is when I use like in a sentence and there are not just 1 verb after it I mean if I said for example :I like shopping in malls and walk in parks and eat in restaurants,and meet my friends in cafes . >>> or should I say : I like shopping in malls and walking in parks and eating in restaurants,and meeting my friends in cafes . which one is correct .

another question : what sentence is more correct : 
I prefer to have fun with my friend but I can have fun with myself or I can have fun alone >..
thank you

Comment: Hey, you're more likely to have questions like these answered on this page :http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the first part is General Reference, and the second part is, well, ***another question***.

Comment: *Have fun with myself* is not idiomatic. It should be *have fun by myself*; or *have fun alone*.

Comment: @WS2: To me, *have fun with myself* has overtones of ***play** with myself* (fiddle with my genitals). Perhaps I just have that sort of mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The idea did cross my mind too!

Comment: @WS2: In which case if *two* of us make the same connection, it might even be possible that's the *reason* it's "not idiomatic". Anyway, even if that's not true (though god knows how one could establish the truth of the matter), there's a strong argument for saying ***learners*** should take that point on board. It'll both help them *remember* what to use/not use, ***and*** avoid giving offense/raising a snigger. Another reason why this should be on ELL?

Answer (score 1):

It makes a more graceful sentence to use the gerund every time you use a verb, i.e.your second example, "I like shopping in malls and walking in parks and eating in restaurants,and meeting my friends in cafes."

This would be an example of parallel construction. Grammar aside it is easier to read.